# Cordova/phonegap filesystem not ready on "deviceready"

Tags: cordova

I'm developing an ios app with Cordova 2.1.0.

It seems that the fileSystem is not available even if "deviceready" event has fired.

```
window.onload = function (){
document.addEventListener("deviceready", getSettings(), false);
}

function getSettings(){
fileSys('settings.txt', 'getContent', null);
}

function fileSys(fileName, action, data){
    alert('hello');    // fires
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    alert('hello');    // does not fire
    //rest of the script breaks
}
```

Script breaks after requesting the filesystem. However, if I wrap the call to fileSys() in a setTimeout, it works. Example:

```
window.onload = function (){
document.addEventListener("deviceready", getSettings(), false);
}

function getSettings(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    fileSys('settings.txt', 'getContent', null);
}, 500);
}

function fileSys(fileName, action, data){
    alert('hello');    // fires
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    alert('hello');    // fires
    //script runs fine
}
```

Any solutions to this?

Comment: It also works fine if I set the timeout to 0. Actually the script has run perfectly fine the whole time with settimeout. But I'd really like to get to the bottom of it before releasing the app. Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setup for deviceready should be

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", getSettings, false);
```

"getSettings()" means run the function now and pass the result to addEventListener.

"getSettings" means pass a function reference to addEventListener so it can be run when the event fires.

Answer (score 2):

Should your fileSys function be prefaced with "function"?

```
function fileSys(fileName, action, data){}
```

Comment: I accidentally left it out of the question. Not in the code. Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put requestFileSystem function in setTimeout(..., 0) too, but the reason was different.

I run requestFileSystem in class constructor and to make the code which is invoked by a callback in the "success" function work I should have constructor already finished at the moment.

My constructor consists of only the requestFileSystem function, and somehow withot zero setTimeout it finished AFTER it's "success" function.

(only for Android - I didn't notice such expirience on iOS)